# Cookies maxAge is not reflecting in chrome debug mode

Tags: java, cookies

I'm currently setting a cookie expiry values like below

```
cookieAdd.setDomain(".localhost");
cookieAdd.setMaxAge(3600);
cookieAdd.setPath(contextName);
```

But If I search that in chrome debug mode it the max age values is always visible as session. Not the value that I set in. Is there anything I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: show the cookieAdd method

Comment: public static void setCookie(HttpServletResponse response, String cookieName, String cookieValue, String contextName)
  {
  Cookie cookieAdd = new Cookie(cookieName, cookieValue);
     cookieAdd.setDomain(".localhost");
     cookieAdd.setMaxAge(3600);
     cookieAdd.setPath("/");
  response.addCookie(cookieAdd);
  }